# How to convert boost::asio::awaitable to std::future?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a function that returns `boost::asio::awaitable`. What is the idiomatic way to convert this awaitable to `std::future`?

Comment: @Frank in its brilliant simplicity that answer has the potential to enlighten a great number of people. Would you care to post that as answer?

Comment: @sehe I don't know if "the library has a button for that" makes for much of a "brilliant" answer, but upon reflection, you are right that this has the potential to unblock a lot of people. Thanks for the prompt. I've removed the previous comment because I feel like the caveat in the answer's foreword is important should this become a commonly-used Q/A.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before we get into the answer, be warned:

You should not, under any circumstance, `get()` or `wait()` a future to a `boost::asio::awaitable` from the same thread as the executor that is running the coroutine.

That being said.

That third parameter to `co_spawn()`, the one almost every example blindly sets to the magic `detached` constant? Its role is to tell `boost::asio` what to do once the coroutine has finished. `detached` simply means "do nothing". So the canonical way to fulfil a future from an `awaitable<>` should be via that mechanism.

Thankfully, asio already provides the `use_future` completion token. Pass that as the third parameter to `co_spawn()` and it will return a `std::future<>` of the matching return type.

```
boost::asio::awaitable<void> foo();
boost::asio::awaitable<int> bar();

std::future<void> foo_fut = boost::asio:co_spawn(io_context, foo(), boost::asio::use_future);
std::future<int> bar_fut = boost::asio:co_spawn(io_context, bar(), boost::asio::use_future);
```

Here's a full example:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using boost::asio::awaitable;
using boost::asio::co_spawn;
using boost::asio::io_context;
using boost::asio::use_future;

awaitable<void> foo() {
  // Simulate foo taking a while to run
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  std::cout << "foo\n";
  co_return;
}

int main() {
  try {
    io_context context;
    std::future<void> fut = co_spawn(context, foo(), use_future);

    std::thread waiter([fut=std::move(fut)](){
        std::cout << "AAA\n";
        fut.wait();
        std::cout << "BBB\n";
    });

    context.run();

    waiter.join();
  
  } catch(const std::exception &ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this means you need access to the io context in order to produce the future.

If you are already inside of a coroutine and have no access to the io_context, then you have to create the future before calling the subroutine, and `co_await` its result before fullfilling the future. `std::promise<>` is perfectly suited for that task:

```
awaitable<void> sub_foo() {
  co_return;
}

awaitable<void> foo() {
  std::promise<void> prom;
  auto fut = prom.get_future();
  // send the future somewhere
  
  co_await sub_foo();

  prom.set_value();

  co_return;
}
```

If you are not within a coroutine, and do not have access to an io_context, then you can't invoke the coroutine in the first place. So either of these approaches should have you covered.